# How to know whether app is installed from Facebook promotion or Google play?

Tags: java, android, google-play

I need to detect my application is installed from Facebook promotion or other market, how could I get this information in my app?

Answer (score 1):

Please use Google Analytics or Firebase Analytics or other analytics tools where you can check daily Below parameters like.

- Track number of daily installation.
- Real Time users accessing your Application.
- Reuse of application.
- On which screens users are spent more time.
- E-Commerce of application
- In which device and OS most users are installing your application.
- Etc.

Please check more details in official site https://analytics.google.com and https://firebase.google.com/ Analytics tools are free no need to spend money for that.

Comment: Is it possible to know programmatically ?

Comment: You can not check programmatically google play not providing such API to detect number of installation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Google Play Install Referrer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/igetinstallreferrerservice) which is easiest to use through the [Play Install Referrer Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library)